# Combining multiple dictionaries to a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine two dictionaries into a single pandas DataFrame in a perticular way.

I have something like this:

**Code**:

```
Dict_fit_parameters={'Sequence1':np.array([1,2,3]),'Sequence2':np.array([4,5,6])}
Dict_standard_deviation={'Sequence1':np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3]),'Sequence2':np.array([0.4,0.5,0.6])}
parameters=['a','b','c']

df=pd.DataFrame(Dict_fit_parameters, columns=['Sequence1','Sequence2'],index=parameters)
```

**Output**:

```
   Sequence1  Sequence2
a          1          4
b          2          5
c          3          6
```

what I would like to do is to add the second dictionary (*Dict_standard_deviation*) so I get:

**Output**

```
           Sequence1      Sequence2
    a          1±0.1          4±0.4
    b          2±0.2          5±0.5
    c          3±0.3          6±0.6
```

Any Ideas how this could be achieved? Entries can, or probably have to be, strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll have to do is cast both the dataframe and dictionary values to string. Then you can directly concatenate them by adding with `'±'` as a separator:

```
df.astype(str) + '±' + np.array(list(Dict_standard_deviation.values())).T.astype(str)

  Sequence1 Sequence2
a     1±0.1     4±0.4
b     2±0.2     5±0.5
c     3±0.3     6±0.6
```